# C - Chaining chars and put it in a variable

Tags: c, text, chaining

I am trying to manipulate text, the text is stored in a variable and i want to save the text until the char ':' but that doesn't work for me

This is what i did:

```
void proccessLine(char *line)
int i=0;
char name=' ';
while(line[i+1]!=':')
{
    name=name+line[i];
    i++;
}
printf("%s\n", &name);
```

Comment: Char is only a character, you use it like a string(array of characters in plain c)

Comment: I agree with @icrew you need a string. Either as `char name[256]` or as `char *name = NULL;` then `malloc` some space.

Comment: Also the `+` operator isn't defined on strings. Since you didn't define name as a string, what you're doing is adding the **values** of the characters into a single number (which overflows at 255), and then print it as if it's a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

As people have mentioned in the comments:

```
int i=0;
char name[256];
while(line[i+1]!=':' && i < 255)
{
   name[i] = line[i];
   i++;
}
name[i] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", name);
```

In C, a "string" does not exist, only an array of `char`s. There are some functions to do stuff with strings (they in fact work on `char` pointers, which is what an array basically is) in `string.h`. As such, the `+` operator doesn't work as string concatenation in C, you'll have to use `strncat` for that.

More info here: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson9.html or any Google search on "C strings" (although you do get some NSFW hits as well then ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way to do this, you can write a function to remove the first occurrence of `:` and return the result.

This function will return the string up to the `:` symbol:

```
 char * StripColon(char *str)
 {
     if(str) return strtok(str, ":");
     return "";

 }
```

Here is an example of how this function can be used:  (and others with prototypes returning `char *`)

```
#include <ansi_c.h>
char * StripColon(char *str);
int  main()
 {
     char line[]="this is a new: string"
     char newString[80];
     newString[0]=0;
     strcpy(newString, StripColon(line));
     printf("String without \":\" %s\n", newString);

      getchar();
      return 0;
 }
```